# Trying to get variable without temporary file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have the following working part of a batch script:

```
CD ".."
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%F IN (`DIR /B "waves"`) DO (
    ECHO %%F>FILE.TMP
    SET /P FILE=<FILE.TMP
    DEL "FILE.TMP"
)
```

Is there a way to directly import %%F to the variable without the need of a temporary file? Everything I've tried did not work.

Comment: You already have it in a variable, in `%%F`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to remove the last 4 characters of the variable. With standard one, I could do it like this:
```
!FILE:~0,-4!
```
That does not work with %%F. Not sure how I could fix this.

Comment: Have you tried `set "FILE=%%F"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the variable directly instead of passing it through a temp file.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`dir /b "waves"`) do set "FILE=%%F"
```

Comment: That is the way I've tried first, but it tells me that ECHO is off. :/

Comment: @NandoLawson - is there a file called `waves` (with _no_ extension) in the same directory as the script? If not, it won't find anything.

Comment: There are files in the directory waves, which is the reason for the "dir" command. Everything works fine when I export %%F to a file and create a variable from it, which means that everything is working. The only thing that does not work is creating a variable from %%F. If someone here knows how to remove the last 4 characters of %%F my problem would also be solved.

Comment: @NandoLawson - All of my tests are successful; I can't replicate your problem. Is there more code that you aren't showing us? Maybe the code in your question is inside another set of parentheses and so you need to use `!file!` instead of `%file%`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess at what you're intending to achieve, print the BaseName of the file whose name comes alpabetically first in the directory `waves`:

```bat
For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D/ON "waves" 2^>NUL')Do Echo(%%~nA&GoTo Next
:Next
Pause
```

The last line was included just to give you time to read the output.

---

You could also set the files' basename as a variable too:

```bat
For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D/ON "waves" 2^>NUL')Do Set "BaseName=%%~nA"&GoTo Next
:Next
Set BaseName 2>NUL&&Pause
```